# Is there any usual attempt in model theory to define someting like the "canonical" signature of a class of structures.

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory

Let $\mathbb{K}$ denote a class of structures, in the usual sense of model theory. Have there been any attempts to define a sensible notion of either

1. *the* usual/canonical siganture with which to axiomatize $\mathbb{K}$,
2. a "category of all signatures suitable to axiomatize $\mathbb{K}$".

If so, what references do you recommend on this?

**Remarks.**

- A standard example of two different signatures being used to axiomatize the same class is the class of all 1-categories: there is of course the usual two-sorted axiomatization, and the less usual but well-known one-sorted one.
- The "syntactic category", in the usual sense of categorical logic, is *vaguely* in the spirit of 2., but seems quite irrelevant actually.
- I have not seen anything substantial in the direction of either 1. or 2. There seems no way, and it seems not be considered a reasonable question.

Comment: Isn't is implicitly part of a structure which signature it is a structure over? You'd need to speak about functor-like things that translate a structure with one signature to a "morally equivalent" one having a different signature.

Comment: For equational structures/theories this is very well done either with the notion of equivalence of varieties/bi-interpretability (the model-theoretic approach), with Lawvere-theories (the categorial approach), or with clone theory (the functional approach- which looks a bit like the notion of equivalence of varieties). All of these theories try to abstract from the signature we know, which may be arbitrary (the usual example is that of group theory, that has many equivalent signatures)

Comment: There's also the notion of concrete categories, where you could see a change of signature as a concrete isomorphism (for instance the very well-known concrete functor over $Set$, $Bool \to BoolRng$ from the concrete category of Boolean algebras to that of Boolean rings)

Comment: The [theory of institutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institution_(computer_science)) and related fields, in particular, [institutional model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutional_model_theory) may (or may not) be relevant.